# Different tmux configs for different sessions?

Tags: configuration, tmux

We have a centos 7 machine that many developers use with tmux 1.8 under the **same user**. Is it possible for us to have personal configs for each tmux session, while also leaving the default config intact for new (default) sessions?

Answer (score 12):

As @asmodean correctly mentioned, the way to use multiple tmux instances on the same machine (with the same user) is to use two different sockets. A socket name can be given using `-L` option.

### Usage

#### Create tmux instances

- first session:

  `tmux -L userA -f ~/.tmux-userA.conf`
- second session:

  `tmux -L userB -f ~/.tmux-userB.conf`

#### Join instances

`tmux -L userA attach
tmux -L userB attach`

#### Other tmux commands

Other commands work with `-L` option. For example, to list userA and userB sessions:

`tmux -L userA list-sessions
tmux -L userB list-sessions`

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I did to achieve per session configuration in tmux.

```
set-hook -g after-new-session 'if -F "#{==:#{session_name},emacs}" "source ~/.tmux/.tmux.conf.emacs" "source ~/.tmux/.tmux.conf.amos"'
set-hook -g after-new-window 'if -F "#{==:#{session_name},emacs}" "source ~/.tmux/.tmux.conf.emacs" "source ~/.tmux/.tmux.conf.amos"'
```

Answer (score -1):

`tmux` can be invoked as `tmux -f /path/to/tmux.conf`.  Since everyone is logging in as the same user, you could create a directory of user configuration files for `tmux`.  For example `/home/username/tmux/userA.tmux.conf`.  UserA would then start their tmux session with:

```
tmux -f ~/tmux/userA.tmux.conf
```

If you wanted to simplify thing for the users, you could make alias entries for each user in the `~/.bashrc` file for example if you are using bash.  Each line would look like:

```
alias tmuxuserA='tmux -f /home/username/tmux/userA.tmux.conf'
```

Then userA would invoke their session with the command `tmuxuserA`.

Comment: Sadly, I this doesn't seem to work. As per the man page, "tmux loads configuration files once when the server process has started.  The source-file command may be used to load a file later". So `-f` only works if tmux is fresh and has no running session. Using `source` updates the config for all running sessions. I feel what I am asking cannot be done using tmux alone.

Comment: If the users don't need to communicate between sessions, you can use the `-L` option to specify a socket name.  A unique server will be started for each socket, which _can_ use different config files.  You can even add it to the alias: `alias tmuxuserA='tmux -L userA -f /home/username/tmux/userA.tmux.conf'`.

Comment: @asmodean, you should add that as it's own answer.  Running independent instances on separate sockets is the solution for the stated problem.