# On Linux, source different .zshrc files for different apps

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh, source, profile

Based on three questions:

- [Use different profiles with ZSH (in different terminal apps)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420204/use-different-profiles-with-zsh-in-different-terminal-apps?rq=1), but deisgned only for macOS
- [Different tmux configs for different sessions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343438/different-tmux-configs-for-different-sessions), but I want to use different .zshrc files for different terminal apps (Deepin Terminal, Tilix and VSCode's integrated terminal)
- [.desktop file with .bashrc environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542152/desktop-file-with-bashrc-environment), but unsuccessfull.

**tl:dr** – for example:

- `.zshrc`

```bsh
if [ -f /usr/bin/tilix ]; then
  if [ -f ~/tilix.zshrc ]; then
    source ~/tilix.zshrc
  fi
elif [ -f /usr/bin/deepin-terminal ]; then
  if [ -f ~/deepin-terminal.zshrc ]; then
    source ~/deepin-terminal.zshrc
  fi
elif [ -f /usr/bin/code-insiders ]; then
  if [ -f ~/code-insiders.zshrc ]; then
    source ~/code-insiders.zshrc
  fi
else
    source ~/tilix.zshrc
fi
```

- And the files Deepin Terminal's and Tilix's desktop files:

```
Exec=bash -c 'source $HOME/deepin-terminal.zshrc && deepin-terminal'
Exec=bash -c 'source $HOME/tilix.zshrc && tilix'
```

- VSCode's `settings.json`:

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "source $HOME/code-insiders.zshrc && /usr/bin/zsh"
}
```

But nothing worked.

Maybe I should use `devilspie`, but I am not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### From the terminal side

In the configuration of each terminal or terminal launcher, arrange to set an environment variable, e.g. `TERM_SUBTYPE=tilix` or `TERM_SUBTYPE=deepin` or `TERM_SUBTYPE=vscode`. In your `.zshrc`, check the value of this variable:

```
case $TERM_SUBTYPE in
  tilix) …;;
  …
  '') …;;
esac
```

The `'')` line is the case when nothing has set `TERM_SUBTYPE`. You can leave it out if you have nothing to do in this case.

#### From the shell side

The terminal emulator is usually the parent of the shell, so check the parent process.

```
case ${$(ps -p $PPID -o comm=):t} in
  tilix) …;;
  deepin-terminal) …;;
  code-insiders) …;;
  *) …;
esac
```

The `*)` line is a fallback if the parent process is not one of the recognized cases. You can leave it out if you have nothing to do in this case.

Comment: Should it be `;;` instead of `;`? It seemed that none of them worked yet. I am using Arch Linux. Does Arch Linux understand `TERM_SUBTYPE` when it does not exist?

Comment: AH, based on the first of three question cited above, I replaced for `ps -o comm= -p $PPID`, and it worked now. But I am waiting for your answer about `TERM_SUBTYPE`.

Comment: @GustavoReis `;` instead of `;;` was a typo, I've fixed it. I've also added an explanation of the case when `TERM_SUBTYPE` is not set. Do note that `TERM_SUBTYPE` is a name that I made up: to use this solution, you need to configure each of your terminals to set it (and I don't know any of the three you mentioned so I can't help you there).